# inject script chrome extension fire only hard refresh

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I try to inject script into facebook, below code work when I open facebook or refresh the page. But if I click on the home icon at the left top, the alert won't fired.

I tried to wrap it with `$(function(){});` it doesn't work too.

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({}, function(response) {
    var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);

        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        //when page is done loading
        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        alert('x');
    }, 10);
});
```

Any solution?

Comment: It's not clear where your code is, what's in manifest.json but anyway facebook is a dynamically updated site so see [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].